# JSON to get the value in the Freebase API

Tags: php, json, google-api, freebase

I am new to Google APIs and am trying to get a particular value using the Freebase API in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). I somehow designed the MQL and my MQL is currently as below.

```
[{
  "id": "/m/03np_7",
  "key": [{
    "namespace": "/wikipedia/en_title",
    "*": null
  }]
}]
```

For the above MQL, I am trying to get the value in a program using PHP. My code is as below.

```
<?php
        class Freebase{
            private $api_key = 'my-api-key';
            public function search($query, $filter = '', $start = 0, $limit = 10, $exact = 'false'){

                if(!empty($query)){
                    $query = urlencode($query);
                    $url    = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query='. $query;
                    $url .= '&key=' . $this->api_key;
                    $url .= '&namespace=wikipedia/en_title';
                    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
                }
            }
        }

        $freebase = new Freebase();
        $result = $freebase->search('/m/03np_7');
        var_dump(json_decode("$result"));
?>
```

I want to get the result as **"name":"University of Texas at Arlington"**

Answer (score 0):

Following query might help. You can also test it out on http://www.freebase.com/query

```
[{
  "id": "/m/03np_7",
  "name": null
}]
```